# Rails / How to run csv export in background to avoid slow queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if anyone had any good ideas for running an csv/excel export query in the background that will minimize on query loads. For results that are 10k+ could cause slow queries.

Comment: Have you hear about jobs queue? I think that is the solution http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32

Answer (score 1):

Well i would recommend you to use [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/).  This is the way i envision

1. You click on the export button
2. Wrap your method which holds the entire sql's/activerecord job and place it inside a sidekiq worker.
3. Once the csv is generated make it available at a file system and a person can download it from there.

The benefit from this is that sidekiq will help you fasten the SQL queries and distribute load properly and secondly you won't be running into a browser timeout issue because of long queries taking time to load and streaming excel/csv at browser.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these popular background job libraries. This is a common problem.

[Resque](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32)

[Others](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32)

[RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32)